# How do I get a button to run a function in a fragment?

Tags: java, android, onclick, onclicklistener

I have a fragment and I want a button to run the function Calculate() when I press it. My fragment is also based from one of the templates.

I've tried the XML android:onClick thing, though I assume its looking inside MainActivity instead of the Fragment so it throws an error.
I've also followed trying to use an OnClickListener from another post, though setting it up (as in code inside OnCreateCiew) gave errors, though it might just be my amateur knowledge of how it works.

This is my calculate function (the function I'm trying to get to run when my button is clicked), which is inside the fragment activity:

```java
    public void Calculate(View v) {
        EditText InitialVelocityInput = getView().findViewById(R.id.initialVelocityInput);
        EditText VelocityInput = getView().findViewById(R.id.velocityInput);
        EditText AccelerationInput = getView().findViewById(R.id.accelerationInput);
        EditText TimeInput = getView().findViewById(R.id.timeInput);

        Log.d("bing", "bing");
    }
```

If needed, [heres the whole fragment activity](https://pastebin.com/vjMRS10k)

When using the XML onclick, my app just crashes when the button is pressed.
When using OnClickListener, I can't even compile because of errors.
I don't have much coding expertise to know what the template fragment code is doing, but I assume its conflicting with however I'm setting up the OnClickListener.

Here's how I tried to set up my OnClickListener:

```
    Button calculatebutton;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View kinematicsCalculatorView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_fragment_calculator_kinematics, container, false);
        calculatebutton = (Button) kinematicsCalculatorView.findViewById(R.id.calculateButton);
        calculatebutton.setOnClickListener(this);
        return kinematicsCalculatorView;
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
       // return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_fragment_calculator_kinematics, container, false);

    }


    public void onClick(View v) {
        EditText InitialVelocityInput = getView().findViewById(R.id.initialVelocityInput);
        EditText VelocityInput = getView().findViewById(R.id.velocityInput);
        EditText AccelerationInput = getView().findViewById(R.id.accelerationInput);
        EditText TimeInput = getView().findViewById(R.id.timeInput);

        Log.d("bing", "bing");
    }
```

However, the `this` in `calculatebutton.setOnClickListener(this);` shows up as an error, (`setOnClickListener(android.view.View.OnClickListener) in View cannot be applied to (com.example.myApp.FragmentCalculatorKinematics)`). onClick method is shown as never being used.

Comment: Hey, can you show us how you were setting it up and exactly what error you got?

Comment: @PabiMoloi Added additional information about onClickListener

Comment: You may implement the callbacks directly into your code. Or you need to implement the `View.OnClickListener` interface to your main fragment class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found somewhat of a solution...
Instead of putting my method inside the FragmentActivity, I just placed it into MainActivity and set android:OnClick="Calculate" in the fragment's XML file. Though I'm not sure if theres any repurcussions from doing this.

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement `View.OnClickListener` **interface** to your `fragment` class.

Here's a snippet of code.

```
public class MyFragment extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener{  // implements the View.OnClickListener interface here

Button calculatebutton;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View kinematicsCalculatorView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_fragment_calculator_kinematics, container, false);
    calculatebutton = (Button) kinematicsCalculatorView.findViewById(R.id.calculateButton);
    calculatebutton.setOnClickListener(this);
    return kinematicsCalculatorView;
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
   // return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_fragment_calculator_kinematics, container, false);

}


public void onClick(View v) {
    switch(v.getId()){  // getting the id of clicked item.
       case R.id.calculateButton:  // When the button will pressed.
         EditText InitialVelocityInput = getView().findViewById(R.id.initialVelocityInput);
        EditText VelocityInput = getView().findViewById(R.id.velocityInput);
        EditText AccelerationInput = getView().findViewById(R.id.accelerationInput);
        EditText TimeInput = getView().findViewById(R.id.timeInput);

        Log.d("bing", "bing");
        break;
    }
}}
```

Hope this will work for you.

Answer (score 0):

If you added fragment to activity by XML:
From activity class:

- `YourFragmentClass  fragment = (YourFragmentClass)(yourActivity.getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(fragment_id));.`

You also can find fragment inside an activity by tag (tag is a string that you assign to the fragment when you promatically add fragment to activity).

- `YourFragmentClass  fragment = (YourFragmentClass)(yourActivity.getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(fragment_tag));`.

After having gotten fragment, you now can call the fragment methods from activity by set OnClickListener for button.

```
btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
{
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v)
    {
       fragment.methodOfFragment();
    }
});
```